# surjective algebra homomorphism $k\widetilde{G} \to k_\alpha G$

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology

I am having trouble understanding the following statement:

Let $Z$ be an abelian group written multiplicatively and let $1 \to Z \to \widetilde{G} \xrightarrow{\pi} G \to 1$ be a central extension of a group $G$ by $Z$. For any $x \in G$ choose $\widetilde{x} \in \widetilde{G}$ such that $\pi(\widetilde{x}) = x$ and denote by $\beta$ the 2-cocycle in $Z^2(G;Z)$ determined by $\widetilde{x}\widetilde{y} = \beta(x,y) \widetilde{xy}$ for $x,y$ in $G$. Let $\nu: Z \to k^\times$ be a group homomorphism. Then $\alpha = \nu\beta$ is a 2-cocycle in $Z^2(G;k^\times)$ and map sending $z\widetilde{x}$ to $\nu(z)x$ induces a surjective algebra homomorphism $k\widetilde{G} \to k_\alpha G$ where $k_\alpha G$ is the twisted group algebra.

Question: so if I have $m_\widetilde{x} z\widetilde{x} \in k\widetilde{G}$, would it be mapped to $m_\widetilde{x}\nu(z)x$. And what is the kernerl of this map?
Any help would be appreciated!